# Response header "Cache-control" visible in PostMan - but not curl -i?

Tags: java, spring, curl, http-headers

Getting some weird behavior here when using the following spring filter.

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)  throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.addHeader("cache-control", "no-store");
    response.addHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

It is configured in XML as well, and I know it works, because when I send a request, I am always able to see the "pragma" header in there, no matter what happens.

But the interesting thing here, is that when I hit this from curl - I get the following headers back :

```
Date: Wed, 19 Apr 2017 20:45:48 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="Spring Security Application"
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Server: Jetty(9.2.10.v20150310)
```

But whenever I make the same request via a rest client (such as postman) I see the following headers : [Image posted here because I am not allowed to embed images on stackoverflow just yet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4xhw.png)

Any idea why this would happen?

EDIT FOR FURTHER INFORMATION : I also see both headers in the network section of developer tools if I hit this from a browser. No idea why it wont appear in curl.

ALSO, I cannot use an interceptor for this as management have decided they don't like them.